# How to get every descendant of node using XPath in java?

Tags: java, xpath

I'm using this code, but I'm not sure what should the XPath expression look like.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("XXXX");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Let's say there's a tree:

```
<animal>
    <big>
        <elephant>
            <white_elephant>

            </white_elephant>
        </elephant>
    </big>
    <small>
    </small>
</animal>
```

I would like to get every descendant of node big: (**elephant**, **white_elephant**) + **big** itself

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I've tried severals combination that I found on the web but those didn't work. Honestly, right now I dont have time to learn XPath, thats why I've asked here.

Comment: Have you tried something like, "/animal/big | /animal/big/*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `descendant-or-self`-axis:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//big/descendant-or-self::*");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Wikipedia is a good source to get a overview over different axis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Axis_specifiers

Edit: As Jens Erat mentions in the comments, you can shorten `/descendant-or-self::` to `//` - it's just an abbreviation:

```
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//big//*");
```

Comment: There is an abbreviation for this axis, you can also use `//big//*` instead.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I thought, // would be a abbreviation for descendant only. I will edit my answer.